Make a seamless texture sampling over a rectangle transformed by affine 3x3 matrix
Question background:
I need to align two images with the same resolution and display the alignment on an OpenGL canvas. So I prepared the vertices like so:

float vertices[] = {
        // positions
        0.0f,  0.0f,     // bottom left
        width,  0.0f,    // bottom right
        0.0f, height,    // top left
        width,  0.0f,    // bottom right
        0.0f, height,    // top left
        width, height,   // top right
};

This way I can draw any number of images on top the other using the same shader, I just send the texture and a transformation matrix to the shader per each aligned image.
With the following vertex and fragment shader, the effect is working as expected:
Vertex shader:
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex_in;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat3 cvAffine; // OpenCV affine transformation matrix

const vec2 texture_coord[] = {
  vec2( 0.0, 0.0),
  vec2( 1.0, 0.0),
  vec2( 0.0,  1.0),
  vec2( 1.0,  0.0),
  vec2( 0.0,  1.0),
  vec2( 1.0,  1.0)
};


void main(){
    vec3 cvCoord = vec3(vertex_in.xy,1.0f); //Create homogenous 2D vector for 3x3 mat mult.
    vec3 transformedCoord = cvAffine*cvCoord; //Transform the image
    gl_Position = vec4((transformedCoord.xy*0.0002), 0.0, transformedCoord.z); //Scale it down for us to see it
    TexCoord = texture_coord[gl_VertexID]; //Send a texture coordinate to the frag. shader
};

Fragment shader
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D texture;
void main(){
    FragColor = texture(texture, TexCoord);
}

The effect:

The actual question:
When I modify this line in the vertex shader:
gl_Position = vec4((transformedCoord.xy*0.0002), 0.0, transformedCoord.z);

with supposedly equivalent line:
gl_Position = vec4(((transformedCoord.xy/transformedCoord.z)*0.0002), 0.0, 1.0);

the alignment breaks:

And there is this common problem with many names:

Affine Texture mapping
Perspective correct Texture mapping
Projective Texture mapping
Trapezoid texture mapping

How is it possible that Vector(xW,yW,z*W,W) is not equal to Vector(x,y,z,1)? Or at least the fragment shader does not agree with that? I need to have 1 in gl_Position.w component as it allows me to further transform pictures around the canvas while preserving the alignment. I have touched the w component of the uv texture space and project it in some way but I was not successful. How to properly transform the texture coordinates so that the texture is sampled uniformly across the whole distorted two-triangle rectangle?
The geometry itself does not change between the modification, only the texture is drawn differently.

The 3x3 matrix you get from OpenCV is not an affine transformation, but rather a 2d projective transformation. OpenGL needs the W coordinate to correctly do perspective interpolation. If you divide by  W yourself, OpenGL doesn't have the necessary information to do perspective interpolation.
For more details about how OpenGL does the perspective interpolation, you can read this answer.

I need to have 1 in gl_Position.w component as it allows me to further transform pictures around the canvas while preserving the alignment

You don't need the 1 there. You can transform your pictures by correctly composing your 3x3 matrix with the desired transformation.
